# How to keep speaker muted on a MacBook Pro (2018) when joining the Skype for Business conference?

Tags: macbook, macos-mojave, skype-for-business

I sit in the offline meeting and joining parallel the same meeting per Skype for Business, because I need to present for online participants. Despite of speakers being muted, my MacBook Pro (2018) plays a very loud join sound and then the huge noise is coming due to sound feedback loop (presenter connected the sound station in the meeting room with sensitive microphones). I muted again the speaker and all was silent again.

I tried again joining the Skype meeting afterwards and confirmed that Skype for Business really un-mutes my speaker, when I join the call.

I never experienced such problem with Windows - if the mic or speaker was muted during the joining of the presentation, they also remained muted.

I'd like to have the same behavior as by Windows - if I muted the speaker, it shall remain so.

I searched Google, but I didn't find anything. May be anybody knows, if it is possible to keep speakers muted when I join the Skype for Business meeting?

I have the latest macOS Mojave 10.14.3 and use Skype for Business 16.24.191.

Comment: What model/year of MacBook Pro do you have? One simple solution would be to simply insert a headphone into the jack of the MacBook while in meetings; all audio out would go through the headphones and the sound would be effectively muted.

Comment: Hi Jack ! I am Using MacBook Pro 2018, and I’m not caring headsets with me when I go to meetings. Would be great to have do something with the software or hardware itself. Thank you for interesting trick though :)

Comment: Well, you can always get a cheap pair of headphones and just cut off the 3.5mm jack off the end and use that as a physical “mute” button.